# Only repository name showing on the public link created by Github

Tags: html, github

I am new in web developing. I have been practicing HTML for 1 week. I made a project about my cv. But whenever I try to make a repository of those html files on github, I get a public link. And when I click on the public link, only the repository name shows, not my websites. As I am a beginner, how can I solve this problem?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvJzz.png)

Comment: put your github profile link then community will be able to guide you better

Answer (score 1):

Move your website's files into the folder that GitHub just created when you made the repository (i.e. farhad.github.io) IMPORTANT: Your homepage HTML file must be called "index.html", and it must exist in the top-level directory.
also take look at below repository, with the help of CNAME file you can set your own domain too.
https://github.com/irjs/irjs.github.io

Comment: Thank you so much for you help.
It worked successfully...
As I am a beginner in Web Development,
I don't know such things about the full journey throughout learning it and the journey of web development in professional life.
Could you please guide me as a mentor that how should I prepare myself for the upcoming times?

Comment: @Md.AbdullahAntor Yeah of course, let's get in touch and I'll help, also if you find this answer helpful mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thank you so much.
But how can I contact you?

Comment: @Md.AbdullahAntor It would be better If u r using telegram messenger here is my id
https://t.me/mrfarhad7 otherwise contact with mail, mehryari.f@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

you must have "index.html"
file in top level directory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).